# NoSuchMethodError HashCode.fromString when using com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.10.0

Tags: android, guava, android-gradle-plugin

If you are using com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.10.0 and gradle 1.12, you might get this error.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Failed to notify task execution graph listener.

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.hash.HashCode.fromString(Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/google/common/hash/HashCode;
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.hash.HashCode.fromString(Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/google/common/hash/HashCode;

Answer (score 6):

HashCode.fromString in only in guava 15+ and somehow you may be pulling in an older version of guava. You should figure out why it is pulling in an old guava version. It might be some other dependency in your buildScript ( like CheckStyle 5.7 ).

As a workaround you can add an explicit dependency on guava 15.

```
buildscript {

  ....

  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.10.0'

    classpath 'com.google.guava:guava:15.0'
```